# What role does "as" play in the sentence?

Tags: clauses

What role does "as" play in the following sentence?

> When the journalist again failed to reply, the editor reluctantly published the article as it had originally been written.

Comment: He published it _in the form in which_ it had been written. Presumably he had wanted to ask the journalist to make some changes.

Comment: This is a comparative construction, where the preposition "as" is the comparative governor with the comparative clause "it had originally been written" as its complement.  The _as_ phrase is equivalent to a relative construction with "form" as head, cf. "... published the article in the same form that it been written in". The _as_ phrase functions as objective predicative complement. It can be analysed as  "the editor published the article in _x_ form, it had been written in _y_ form; _x=y_.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting. I got the meaning of that. Just curious about the syntax related to "as" here.

Comment: @BillJ, thanks for the clear explanation.